# AngularJS: Loading plug-in object inside Service/Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is regarding the Browser plug-in loading from my angular web application.
I have jquery based web application. Now, I am re-writing some portions(mainly, front end) using Angular framework.
I am facing a problem in loading my custom browser plug-in in my application. Earlier, in Jquery based app, I was using `document.getElementById(#objectId)` to instanstiate the plug-in object which is declared in main HTML file. It was working well.
But, in angular, i am not able to find proper way to load the plugin object.

Could somebody give some pointers to achieve this ?

Here is my plug-in object declaration in HTML:

```
<div id="pluginContainer" style="display: none;">
    <object id="myPlugIn" type="application/x-myPluginType" width="0px" height="0px">
        <param name="onload" value="pluginLoaded" />
    </object>
</div>
```

In Jquery based app:

```
var pluginObject = document.getElementById('myPlugin');
```

Thanks,
BMS

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular's `jQLite` to select a DOM element.

You can use these,

```
$scope.pluginObject = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myPlugin'));
```

See doc [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element).

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JANhr/).

Comment: Thanks Devo. Could you help me to set event listeners for the plugin object.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tiny `directive` and get the element from it. AngularJS makes it really simple. I've created a directive called `plugin-object`. 
Please take a look at the code below.

Working Plunkr here (http://plnkr.co/edit/ji5hT95vcDIuwpEcJlVe?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>myApp</title>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script>

  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


  myApp.directive('pluginObject', [function ($document) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var pluginElement = element;

        var pluginContainer = angular.element('#pluginContainer');

        var justTest = $('#t1');


        pluginElement.bind('click', function(event){
          console.log(event.target);
        });

        pluginContainer.bind('click', function(event){
          console.log(event.target);
        });

        justTest.bind('click', function(event){
          console.log(event.target);
        });


      }
    };
  }])

  </script>

  <style>
    #t1 { border: 2px solid gray; background-color: #f00; }
    #myPlugIn { height: 100px; width: 100px;}
    #pluginContainer { border: 2px solid gray; background-color: blue; width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;}
  </style>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div id="pluginContainer">
      <object id="myPlugIn" plugin-object type="application/x-myPluginType">
          <param name="onload" value="pluginLoaded" />
      </object>
  </div>

  <div id="t1">TEST</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You could even use jQuery inside the directive as you normally would do - see third option `pluginJQueryWay`, BUT I wouldn't recommend that as it's not really necessary - the more AngularJS you think and less jQuery it's better. :)

Also make sure you are no trying to instantiate the plugin or bind events to it from the `controller` - try to keep any DOM manipulation inside the directive (best practice!).

If you get it right directives will simplify your HTML and serve as reusable building blocks across your application that are not depending on any specific `controller` or `$scope`.
It is a beautiful thing ;)

If you want to bind some event you can use `.bind` - check code below using the `pluginAngularWay2` :

```
    var pluginAngularWay2 = angular.element('#t1');

    pluginAngularWay2.bind('click', function(event){
      console.log(event.target);
    });
```

You can of course bind to other events rather than just **click** 
`.bind('change', function(){...})` and so on.

Comment: Thank you dluz. I have tried to add an event listener for the plug-in objects(pluginAngularWay1 , pluginAngularWay2, pluginJQueryWay). But, I am getting the below error.  "Error: pluginJQueryWay.addEventListener is not a function". Could you please help me to handle this error. My plugin will throw some events once it gets some data from the server. My angular web app should catch those events. Thanks.